# Count distinct from a Recordset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a recordset, I want to count how many different values has a "column" of that recordset.

In a SQL query it would be something like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(tag) 
FROM x 
GROUP BY tag
```

Where *x* would be the recordset and *tag* would be the "column"

For example, if *tag* is: y1,y1,y1,y2,y3,y3,y4,y4,y5 I want to get 5, since there are 5 different values for *tag*.

The problem is that I can't execute a SQL query to the recordset.

Comment: SQL Server and MS Access are rather different.  Which are you really using?

Comment: Sorry, MS-Access

Comment: A recordset has it's source. You should just query from that source, instead of querying the recordset. Querying a recordset indeed is not possible (you can filter and order, though), and there are no easy alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tag)
FROM x;
```

MS Access doesn't support this standard functionality, so you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(tag)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM x) as xx
```

Comment: But can x be a recordset? The data is stored in a recordset

Comment: No, data is always stored in tables. A recordset is a way to access that data. A query is another. @bimmer55